# Context Free Grammar $L=\{a^ib^{2i}c^{2i} | i>1\}$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

In one of my exams I needed to find a CFG for $L=\{a^ib^{2i}c^{2i} | i>1\}$.

however, it really seemed to me that it is not a CFG.
I tried to show it is not using the pumping lemma, and think I managed, but I don't really know if I did something wrong there.

So was I wrong or the question is wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your language is not context-free. You can see this by applying the inverse of the homomorphism which sends $a$ to $a$, $b$ to $bb$ and $c$ to $cc$; this results in the language $\{a^ib^ic^i : i > 1\}$, which differs from a well-known non-context-free language by just a finite number of words.